# Get all children by parent id recursively (php)

Tags: php, algorithm, recursion, children

I have a following array:

```
[
12 => ['parent_id' => null],
13 => ['parent_id' => 12],
14 => ['parent_id' => 12],
15 => ['parent_id' => 12],
16 => ['parent_id' => 13],
17 => ['parent_id' => 13],
18 => ['parent_id' => 12],
19 => ['parent_id' => 16],
20 => ['parent_id' => 18],
21 => ['parent_id' => 20],
22 => ['parent_id' => 20],
]
```

I am trying to get all chidren recursively by key(id):
for instance for
13 just want to get `[16, 17, 19]`,
for 18 - `[20, 21, 22]`.

Each node has one or more children.

I am trying to get for item like this, but cannot get working properly:

```
function getRecursiveChildren($id, $items, $kids = [])
{
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] === $id) {
            $kids[] = $this->getRecursiveChildren($id, $items, $kids);
        }
    }

    return $kids;
}
```

Can someone help or maybe hint or provide correct solution for this?
Thanks!

Comment: "... cannot get working properly". For the two example scenarios you have provided, which results _do_ you get?

Comment: I am getting just one child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
function getRecursiveChildren($id, $items): array
{
    $kids = [];
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] === $id) {
            $kids[] = $key;

            if ($id !== $key) {
                array_push($kids, ...getRecursiveChildren($key, $items));
            }
        }
    }
    return $kids;
}
```

if order is important for you, you can order the array

Comment: Very nice solution, but may cause problems, if `$id` === `$key` ("Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted"). I added condition to your post for `array_push` (`if ($id !== $key) {`) only entering which function is called recursively.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = [
    12 => [ 'parent_id' => null ],
    13 => [ 'parent_id' => 12 ],
    14 => [ 'parent_id' => 12 ],
    15 => [ 'parent_id' => 12 ],
    16 => [ 'parent_id' => 13 ],
    17 => [ 'parent_id' => 13 ],
    18 => [ 'parent_id' => 12 ],
    19 => [ 'parent_id' => 16 ],
    20 => [ 'parent_id' => 18 ],
    21 => [ 'parent_id' => 20 ],
    22 => [ 'parent_id' => 20 ]
];

function search(array $arr, int $parentId): array {
  $keys = array_keys(array_filter($arr, fn($value) => $value['parent_id'] === $parentId));
  foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $keys = array_merge($keys, search($arr, $key));
  }
  return $keys;
}

$result = search($data, 18);
```