# Getting nth-children ids recursively using function (php)

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table of two columns `id` and `parent_id`

```
|-id-|-parent_id-|
| 1  | 0         |
| 2  | 1         |
| 3  | 16        |
| 4  | 19        |
| 5  | 19        |
| 6  | 2         |
| 7  | 2         |
| 8  | 6         |
| 9  | 19        |
| 10 | 4         |
| 11 | 4         |
| 12 | 2         |
| 13 | 19        |
| 14 | 13        |
| 15 | 2         |
| 16 | 19        |
| 17 | 13        |
| 18 | 19        |
| 19 | 1         |
|-id-|-parent_id-|
```

I am trying to get all the children recursively

So what I made a function `getRecursiveChildren()` to check each `id` and if this `id` has children I push them to an array BUT for some reason this is not working!

here is my code:

```
<?php

    $passed_parent_id=1;

    $q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `_del_test` WHERE `isActive` = '1' AND `parent_id` = '$passed_parent_id'");
    if($q&&mysqli_num_rows($q)>0)
    {
        # get all kids
        while($qr=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
            $sys_id = $qr['sys_id'];
            $parent_id = $qr['parent_id'];
            getRecursiveChildren($sys_id,$parent_id);
        }
    }


    function getRecursiveChildren($id, $items): array
    {
        $kids = [];
        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
            if ($item['parent_id'] === $id) {
                $kids[] = $key;

                if ($id !== $key) {
                    array_push($kids, ...getRecursiveChildren($key, $items));
                }
            }
        }
        return $kids;
    }
?>
```

Could you please help?! my brain is stuck, and I can't think straight anymore
Thanks

Comment: The `$items` you are passing to your function is a single column value, so why are you trying to foreach over it?

Comment: And what is the actual result you want here? Just saying you want to stick them into an array, is a bit thin.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe , the results I am trying to get is if I pass id=19 for example I want to return all the children of this id no matter how deep it goes.  So, I should get [4-5-9-13-16-18-10-11-14-3]

Comment: regarding `$items` TBH my thought is I need 2 passed value one to get the `parent_id` and the other is to store it's children ids .  I am sure I have issue in the logic here.

Comment: _"So, I should get [4-5-9-13-16-18-10-11-14-3]"_ - 17 should also be in there, no? 17 has 13 as parent, and 13 has 19.

Comment: @CBroe yes you are right, I missed 17

Comment: Related: [Get all children by parent id recursively (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70894640/2943403) and [Get all child, grandchild etc nodes under parent using php with mysql query results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11497202/2943403) and [PHP: Recursively get children of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352689/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

This will create an array in the order of *item > child > child > item > item > item > child > item*:

```
$input = [
  [ 'id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0 ],
  [ 'id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1 ],
  [ 'id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 16 ],
  [ 'id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 19 ],
  [ 'id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 19 ],
  [ 'id' => 6, 'parent_id' => 2 ],
  [ 'id' => 7, 'parent_id' => 2 ],
  [ 'id' => 8, 'parent_id' => 6 ],
  [ 'id' => 9, 'parent_id' => 19 ],
  [ 'id' => 10, 'parent_id' => 4 ],
  [ 'id' => 11, 'parent_id' => 4 ],
  [ 'id' => 12, 'parent_id' => 2 ],
  [ 'id' => 13, 'parent_id' => 19 ],
  [ 'id' => 14, 'parent_id' => 13 ],
  [ 'id' => 15, 'parent_id' => 2 ],
  [ 'id' => 16, 'parent_id' => 19 ],
  [ 'id' => 17, 'parent_id' => 13 ],
  [ 'id' => 18, 'parent_id' => 19 ],
  [ 'id' => 19, 'parent_id' => 1 ]
];

function extractChildren(array $array, int $parent_id): array {
  return
    array_merge(
      ...array_map(
        fn($item) => [ $item['id'], ...extractChildren($array, $item['id']) ],
        array_filter($array, fn($item) => $item['parent_id'] === $parent_id)
      )
    );
}

$result = extractChildren($input, 19);

print_r($result);
```

From inside to outside:

- `array_filter` removes the items where 'parent_id' does not match.
- `array_map` takes the 'id' part from an item, and also gets the items children by calling *extractChildren* recursively.
- `array_merge` with the spread operator flattens the result.

Output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 4
  [1] => 10
  [2] => 11
  [3] => 5
  [4] => 9
  [5] => 13
  [6] => 14
  [7] => 17
  [8] => 16
  [9] => 3
  [10] => 18
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` to extract all items that have a specific parent. And then you loop over those extracted items again, and do the same thing recursively.

Take note that this function does not return only the child IDs, it still returns the [child, parent] tuples - necessary for it to work. But you can then use `array_column` to extract only the child IDs, if you want.

```
$data = json_decode('[[1,0],[2,1],[3,16],[4,19],[5,19],[6,2],[7,2],[8,6],[9,19],[10,4],
                  [11,4],[12,2],[13,19],[14,13],[15,2],[16,19],[17,13],[18,19],[19,1]]');

function getRecursiveChildren($id, $items) {
    $res = array_filter($items, function($item) use ($id) {
       return $item[1] === $id;
    });
    foreach($res as $item) {
        $res += getRecursiveChildren($item[0], $items);
    }
    return $res;
}

print_r(array_column(getRecursiveChildren(19, $data), 0));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 13
    [4] => 16
    [5] => 18
    [6] => 10
    [7] => 11
    [8] => 14
    [9] => 17
    [10] => 3
)
```